# What's the rationale of bootstrap 4 using px units for default gutter, but then rem units in px-lg-* and mx-lg-* to modify gutters?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

If you inspect any bootstrap 4 `container > row > col` structure, you will notice that bootstrap 4 uses `15px` paddings and `-15px` margins on left and right. I think the reasoning for not using `rem` is that if user changes default browser size, e.g. by going in chrome://settings/appearance, bootstrap doesn't want to change the **gutter** size as well. *And,* if you choose to change the font-size of the whole website by modifying `font-size` on the root element(`html` in this case), bootstrap 4 wants to still have 15px gutters regardless.

Fair enough makes sense, e.g. Nobody wants a navigation to break by increasing navitem links' padding too much, assuming user has opted for extra large font size in the browser settings, or you just wanna increase `root` font sizing, without affecting the gutter size.

Surprisingly, reading the [gutter section of bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#gutters), I found out they suggest using `px-lg-5` and `mx-lg-n5` to customize gutter width for screen sizes >= 992px. The irony is these classes use paddings and margins in `rem` as following:

```
.ml-lg-n5, .mx-lg-n5 {
    margin-left: -3rem!important;
}

.pr-lg-5, .px-lg-5 {
    padding-right: 3rem!important;
}
```

So this brings me to ask the question:

**What's the rationale of bootstrap 4 using `px` units for default gutter sizeing, but then rem units in `.px-lg-*` and `.mx-lg-*` to modify the gutter sizing?**

Comment: maybe this example helps: let's say you want to buy gold so the weight they use is Gram and when you want to buy fruits they use Kilogram, **1rem => 16px** so instead of **48px** they use **3rem**

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa It doesn't, for one, in our country we don't use grams for gold at all, we use [Tolah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tola_(unit)) and for fruits sometimes 250gms has its own unit and. All the analogies aside. You are implying, 3 rem is easy to remember and use than 48px. But, they use even bigger numbers like 992px, 1200px etc, and mention explicitly why they don't use rems for containers sizes. Your reason doesn't look reasonable.